# Projectile Using Out of date version of svn

Tags: emacs

I'm using the projectile library. When I invoke `projectile-find-file` I get the following error:

```
[svn: E155021: This client is too old to work with the working copy at foo/bar` (format 31). You need to get a newer Subversion client. For more details, see http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#working-copy-format-change
```

From the command line, everything is fine (I'm using version 1.8.13).

Is there anyway that emacs can be using an out of date version? Or even how do I find out what version it is using/how it is invoking svn?

Comment: That's strange. Projectile simply [uses whatever `svn` binary it can find on your path](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/blob/master/projectile.el#L818). Try running `shell-command` (bound to `M-!` by default) and running `which svn` (assuming you're on an OS with `which`). This should print the actual path to the `svn` that Emacs sees. You can compare this with the results from running the same command in your shell and see if they're different.

Comment: Thanks. `M-! which svn` returns `/usr/bin/svn`, while opening an (outside of emacs) terminal gives me `/usr/local/bin/svn`.

Comment: Then you probably want to ensure that `/usr/local/bin/` appears before `/usr/bin/` in the path that Emacs sees. The exact way to do this will depend on a number of things. (a) What OS are you on? (b) How do you launch Emacs? (c) If you launch Emacs from a terminal, which shell are you using (`echo $SHELL` might be helpful here)?

Comment: My emacs path doesn't even contain `/usr/local/bin`. I'm on Mac OS X, and I launch emacs from Quicksilver, which gives me `/applications/Emacs.app`

Running emacs from the terminal/bash gives me a path that includes `usr/local/bin`.

Next steps seem to be verifying whether Quicksilver or the Emacs install causes this.

Comment: Adding `/usr/local/bin/` to Emacs' path is important because that's where _the newer `svn`_ lives, not where Emacs lives. Tell Emacs that it can find executables in `/usr/local/bin/` by adding it to your path (before `/usr/bin/`, so it takes precedence) and it will be able to find the proper `svn`.

Comment: Yes, my path has `/usr/local/bin`, but it's just not present in Emacs. Or are you saying there is some way to modify the path Emacs has from within Emacs?

Comment: There are many ways to set the path. I was trying to leave room for you to select one that you like. However if you don't have any preference, something like [`exec-path-from-shell`](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell) (which was originally written with OSX in mind) might be helpful. It should "ensure environment variables inside Emacs look the same as in the user's shell". It's [available on MELPA](http://melpa.org/#/exec-path-from-shell).

Comment: Thanks. It turns out that the problem is something to do with a difference between the environment in Quicksilver and the environment in my shell (iTerm2). Opening iTerm and executing `open /Application/Emacs.app` gives me Emacs with a path that contains `/usr/local/bin`.

P.S. If you want, you can convert your initial comment to an answer.

Comment: Thanks, I've added a combination of my original comment and my suggestion to use `exec-path-from-shell` as an answer. Glad you got everything working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Projectile [uses whatever `svn` binary it finds in your path](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/blob/master/projectile.el#L818). Try running `which svn` from Emacs (e.g. via `shell-command` / `M-!`) and from your terminal and comparing the paths you get. A difference will indicate that Emacs and your terminal are using different path variables.

Since you are on OSX, and since your terminal uses the expected `svn`, something like [`exec-path-from-shell`](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell) might be helpful:

> Ever find that a command works in your shell, but not in Emacs?
>
> This happens a lot on OS X, where an Emacs instance started from the GUI inherits a default set of environment variables.
>
> This library works solves this problem by copying important environment variables from the user's shell: it works by asking your shell to print out the variables of interest, then copying them into the Emacs environment.

`exec-path-from-shell` is [`available on MELPA`](http://melpa.org/#/exec-path-from-shell).